# Problems with numbered custom styles of theorems beamer

Tags: beamer

I try to use my custom style in beamer documnet, if I use not numbered definitions or another my custom style for theorems and exmaples

```latex
\begin{myDefinition*}{Sample Definition}
This is a sample definition.
\end{myDefinition*}

\begin{myExample*}{Sample Definition}
This is a sample definition.
\end{myExample*}

\begin{myQuestion*}{Sample Definition}
This is a sample definition.
\end{myQuestion*}

\begin{myTheorem*}{Sample Definition}
This is a sample definition.
\end{myTheorem*}
```

All works fine, but if I del `*`, so I want use numbered custom enviroments, I have the such errors:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

I think, this errors related to using a different language pack (when I re-define myDefinition style)

And first symbol of definition (description field after title) not shown... **I don't understand, how to fix this trouble?**

My preamble code:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{concmath}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Assignment},
    colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black!90,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true
}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\setstretch{1.0}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.15cm}

\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
    \normalsize
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{4pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{4pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{4pt}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{%
    \ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount<2
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{%
      #2%
    }}%
    \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
    \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
    \fi%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize}

\usebeamercolor{structure}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black!20,fg=black}

% \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace*{-1ex}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=3.2em\rlap{\hskip-2em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber}\inserttocsubsection\par}

\makeatletter

\define@key{beamerframe}{s}[true]{% stretch
  \beamer@frametopskip=8pt\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=4pt plus 0.0001fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}

\def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{%
    \def\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip{%
      \vskip-\partopsep\vskip-\topsep\vskip-\parskip%
      \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}%
    \everypar{\global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@leftmargin-\beamer@rightmargin\relax}
    % \vspace{-4ex}
   \centering
   \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \vskip -2pt
   \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \usebeamercolor{footline}%
   % \hfill\insertpagenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
   \hfill\insertpagenumber
   \hfill%
   \llap{\insertframenavigationsymbol\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}\par
   \end{minipage}\vskip4pt
}

\makeatother

\definecolor{mytheoremfr}{HTML}{00007B}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myDefinition}{Определение}{enhanced,
    before skip=2mm, after skip=2mm, colback=black!7, colframe=black!65!white, boxrule=0.3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm, yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight}, varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={
        frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
            arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!45!white, right color=tcbcolback!45!white,
            middle color=tcbcolback!45!white]
            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
        },
        interior engine=empty,
    },
    fonttitle= \itshape \bfseries \color{black},
    title={#2},#1
}{def}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=false,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{\textbf{Linear Algebra}}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\thispagestyle{empty}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Intro}

\subsection{Intro I}

\begin{frame}[s, allowframebreaks] \frametitle{Intro I}
\begin{myDefinition}{Вектор}
Бла Бла Бла.
\end{myDefinition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This picture shows my troubleshooting:

[image]

Comment: Can you please include one or more screenshots of your output? Thank you // BTW, your posted code can't compile, as it ends with `\section{Mathematics}`...

Comment: Can you please show your log file? I don't get any error when running your code (after adding the missing `\end{document}`)

Comment: Unrelated: you should clean up your preamble, lots of unnecessary packages

Comment: @MS-SPO

Sorry, I edit my post

Comment: Why are you loading `\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}` 5 times?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Sorry, but when I edit previous custom template, I not delete this blocks  (initial template create another author)https://github.com/SeniorMars/dotfiles/blob/master/latex_template/preamble.tex

Comment: It would be really nice if you would trim down your code to the parts relevant to your question before asking questions. How are several hundred lines of code about sections and frametitles in any way related to a problem with tcolorboxes?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Trim code in my questions... Sorry, for my previous version, initially, I did not remove some code so that the work of other important segments would not be disrupted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Your custom theorems take two mandatory arguments, one for the title and one for the label. You can't just leave one out. At the very minimum, it can be empty, but it can't simply be missing.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\definecolor{mytheoremfr}{HTML}{00007B}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myDefinition}{Определение}{enhanced,
    before skip=2mm, after skip=2mm, colback=black!7, colframe=black!65!white, boxrule=0.3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm, yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight}, varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={
        frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
            arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!45!white, right color=tcbcolback!45!white,
            middle color=tcbcolback!45!white]
            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
        },
        interior engine=empty,
    },
    fonttitle= \itshape \bfseries \color{black},
    title={#2},#1
}{def}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 

\begin{myDefinition}{Вектор}{quack}
Бла Бла Бла.
\end{myDefinition}

\ref{def:quack}

\begin{myDefinition}{Title}{}
Test
\end{myDefinition}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my God, what a stupid mistake, I'm so sorry and express my sincere gratitude!